# How do i adjust my model to stored uploaded images to my database as a link to the image instead of appearing as a blob?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Hi guys I have recently managed to get images to upload to my profile page but when I refresh the page the image disappears. I think this is because how the image is being put into the db.

Here is model:

```
function ProfileImages()
{
    parent::__construct();

}

function exists($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from("profileimages")->where('user', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        return true;
        /*
         echo "user $user exists!";
        $row = $query->row();
        echo " and his profileimage is $row->profileimage";
        */
    }

    else

    {

        return false;
        //echo "no such user as $user!";
    }

}


function putProfileImage($username, $img)
{


    $record = array('user' => $username, 'profileimage' => $img);
    if ($this->exists($username))
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->update('profileimages', $record);

    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->insert('profileimages', $record);

    }

}

function getProfileImage($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from('profileimages')->where('user', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row->profileimage;
    }

    return Null;


}

   }
```

Here is my controller:

```
class HomeProfile extends CI_Controller 
 {


function HomeProfile()
  {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model("profiles");
   $this->load->model("profileimages");
   $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
  }


      function upload()
       {
      $config = array(

        'allowed_types' =>'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
        'upload_path' =>'./web-project-jb/assets/puploads/',
         'max_size' => 10000,
         'max_width' => 1024,
        'max_height' => 768

);


$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$img = $this->session->userdata('img');
$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
$this->profileimages->putProfileImage($username, $this->input->post("profileimage"));
//fail show upload form
if (! $this->upload->do_upload())
{

    $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');


    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $error, $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ));
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');

    //redirect('homeprofile/index');

}

else
{
    //successful upload so save to database


    $file_data = $this->upload->data();


    $data['img'] = '/web-project-jb/assets/puploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];
    // you may want to delete the image from the server after saving it to db
    // check to make sure $data['full_path'] is a valid path
    // get upload_sucess.php from link above
    //$image = chunk_split( base64_encode( file_get_contents( $data['file_name'] ) ) );



    $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $data['profileimages'] = $this->profileimages->getProfileImage($username);


    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $data, $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');


    //redirect('homeprofile/index');
}

  }



  function index()
  {

$username = $this->session->userdata('username');

$data['profileimages'] = $this->profileimages->getProfileImage($username);

$viewData['username'] = $username;
$viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

$this->load->view('shared/header');
$this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
$this->load->view('shared/nav');
//$this->load->view('homeprofile/upload_form', $data);
$this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $data, $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ) );
$this->load->view('shared/footer');
   }

  }
```

If you look at the putprofileimages function in the model I'm think I would put an appends command in here somewhere. I want the filename of the image to appear in the db in the profileimage field. Also Im hoping the profile image will stay on the screen when I refresh

```
<h3><?="Profile Image"?></h3>
 <img src="<?php if (isset($img)) echo base_url($img); ?>" width='300' height='300'/>
  <?=form_open_multipart('homeprofile/upload');?>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" value=""/>
    <?=form_submit('submit', 'upload')?>
    <?=form_close();?> 
    <?php if (isset($error)) echo $error;?>
  </div> 
</div>  
   <div id="secondary">
  <p>
      <?=$profileText;?>
    </p>
    <p>
      <?=form_open('homeprofile/changetext'); ?>
      <?php $msgbox = array(
            'name' => 'profiletext',
            'rows' => '8',
            'cols' => '30',
            );?>
     <?=form_textarea($msgbox);?>       
     </p>
     <p>
      <?=form_submit('submit', 'Change'); ?>
      <?=form_close(); ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: why would you have an exists() func then run the exact same query again to get the row? Just try to get the row and return it, if that is false it doesn't exist. One db connection saved. Anyhow..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply save just the image name in the db like a char field.
Just after your `do_upload` function you can retrieve the image name with `$this->upload->file_name`

Then you can easly save this in the db, not the whole file.

In your view page now you can set via html the image path and then appen just the file name you get from the db query.

Comment: $this->upload->file_name - do I put it in the else part of the do_upload function?

Comment: Also would I need to touch my model at all or could I just use the append in my view?

Comment: In $this->upload->file_name there is the file name.
You need to pass that to your model.
Example:
$data_for_model = array('username'=>$username, 'image'=> $this->upload->file_name);

Answer (score 0):

One quick note - are you using codeigniter 2 ? 
you should set up your constructors this way:

```
 class HomeProfile extends CI_Controller 
 {

 function __construct()
{
    // Call the parent construct
    parent::__construct();

$this->load->model("profiles");
$this->load->model("profileimages");
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));      

 } // end construct
```

And its the same for the models! 
ok in yr model, maybe i'm not getting this but you have

```
 if ($this->exists($username))
```

but your method says

```
 function putProfileImage($username, $img)
```

so if username might be blank, you need to just set a default like

```
function putProfileImage($username = 0, $img)
```

then maybe you could do

```
 if ($username === 0)
```

but personally i would not put insert and update in the same method, split them up, 
will be much easier to debug. 
also -- Did you load the session library in autoload???

Comment: Hi there yes i did load the session library. If its ok I would like to put the insert and update in the same memthod as I find this way easier to understand myself. I'm starting to think is the first function l have in the model even necessary? I think I need the get profileimage to display the image in the page if the page is refreshed. at the moment the image is showing in my database as a 0 - this is after I changed the datatype of the field from Blob to char.

Comment: By the way in the update command do I not put the uploads folder so it can reference this and insert the actual file into the database?$this->db->where('user', $username)->update('profileimages', /*'./uploads/.' */$record);

Comment: this tutorial will help http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-file-uploading-and-image-manipulation/